# package load failed in Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, package

Can someone please help?

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘gtable’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 4.0.2
```

Comment: Hello. Would you please be able to show the relevant section of your code?

Comment: Hi Anna please added info about your system by running this in RStudio `sessionInfo()` and added the output into your questions within a code block

Comment: Hey Sinh, I did so. Is it because I don't have the right version of RStudio to install the package ? Best, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> install.packages("~/Desktop/magrittr_2.0.1.tar", repos = NULL)
> Error in install.packages : type == "both" cannot be used with 'repos = NULL'
> install.packages("~/Desktop/magrittr_2.0.1.tar", repos = NULL, type="source")

- installing *binary* package ‘magrittr’ ...
- DONE (magrittr)

> library(magrittr)
> Fehler: package or namespace load failed for ‘magrittr’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> kann shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/magrittr/libs/magrittr.so' nicht laden:
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/magrittr/libs/magrittr.so, 6): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
> Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib
> Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
> in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib
> Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
> Paket ‘magrittr’ wurde unter R Version 4.0.2 erstellt

Answer (score 0):

R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3 tools_3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

> install.packages("~/Desktop/magrittr_1.5.tar", repos = NULL)
> Error in install.packages : type == "both" cannot be used with 'repos = NULL'
> install.packages("~/Desktop/magrittr_1.5.tar", repos = NULL, type="source")

- installing *source* package ‘magrittr’ ...
  ** Paket ‘magrittr’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  ** help
  *** installing help indices
  ** building package indices
  ** installing vignettes
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
  ** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
- DONE (magrittr)
  Fehler in fetch(key) :
  lazy-load database '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/magrittr/help/magrittr.rdb' is corrupt

> library(magrittr)
> Fehler: package or namespace load failed for ‘magrittr’ in get(method, envir = home):
> lazy-load database '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/magrittr/R/magrittr.rdb' is corrupt
> Zusätzlich: Warnmeldungen:
> 1: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
> Neustart einer unterbrochenen promise evaluation
> 2: In get(method, envir = home) :
> Neustart einer unterbrochenen promise evaluation
> 3: In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1